# Jetpack Compose + most basic buildSrc = build error: IllegalStateException: couldn't find inline method

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I've bumped into an issue, and I'm looking for your advice.

**Given:** a new project:

- app/build.gradle (only relevant blocks shown, omitted the others):

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = project.kotlinVersion
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler_version
    }
}
```

- buildSrc/build.gradle

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

}
```

**When:** I add the `implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'` dependency to `buildSrc/build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
}
```

**Then:** I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't find inline method Landroidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/ViewModelKt;.viewModel$default(Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner;Ljava/lang/String;Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider$Factory;Landroidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/CreationExtras;ILjava/lang/Object;)Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModel;
```

What I've found out is that the above error appears when the Compose compiler version is not set. In my case it is set. If I remove that dependency from `buildSrc/build.gradle` the project builds, and runs normally.

In case you have any ideas I should try, please let me know.

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

By testing, I was receiving different kinds of errors.
In the end I managed to solve it like this:
in `buildSrc/build.gradle` I've added:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10"
    implementation "com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0" // required by hilt
}
```

In the root build.gradle the `version` properties needs to be removed, it looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' apply false
}
```

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is long I'm posting this *"answer"*: for the solution please see the ***UPDATE*** section of the question.